# Attributes method explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I saw this method and I'm not sure of its purpose.

```
def attributes=(attrs = {})
    (attrs||{}).each do |k, v|
      send(:"#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
```

Can someone explain it please?

Comment: It's not well written either. Don't use `(attrs||{})`. Instead use `attrs.each`. `(attrs||{})` was already handled by `attrs = {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is a method in a class, it assigns the attributes to the class.

Suppose we have this class:

```
class NewCar  
  def initialize(name, color, size)    
    @name = name 
    @color = color
    @size = size
  end  
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :size
end  
car = NewCar.new('my car', 'blue', 'small')
```

To change the values we can do:

```
car.name = 'new car'
car.color = 'red' # I hate blue cars
car.size = 'Big' # my car is big
```

Or using `send`:

```
car.send("name=", 'My new car')  
car.send("color=", 'red')  
car.send("size=", 'Big')
```

But you can do it an easier way:

```
class NewCar  
  def initialize(name, color, size)    
    @name = name 
    @color = color
    @size = size
  end  
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :size 
  def attributes=(attrs = {})
    (attrs||{}).each do |k, v|
      send(:"#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
end  
car = NewCar.new("my car", 'blue', 'small')
car.attributes = {color: 'red', size: 'Big'}
```

And here we go, we can add as many attributes as we want.

Note that since the name of the method ends with `=`, Ruby gives you some syntactic sugar for calling this method. Instead of this:

```
car.attributes=({color: 'blue', size: 'small'}
```

you're allowed to do this:

```
car.attributes = {color: 'blue', size: 'small'}
```

Comment: An initializer that takes options in the same format as `attributes` would minimize the amount of code needed here.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this method is to perform assignment of many key/value pairs to attributes of an object. This is a common pattern in Rails, typically you see this in the class methods like `new` and `create` where the values of the attributes of the instance are passed in as arguments to the method.

For example ...

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
end
myDog = Dog.create name: "Rover", breed: "Collie", age: 5
```

Comment: If used in a non activerecord class which also uses `attr_accessor`, what is it doing?

Comment: I think @mhmd's comment above answers this particular scenario you are asking about <code>car.attributes = {color: 'blue', size: 'small'} </code>